# Site off-line error message upon reinstalling from remote to localhost

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I've taken backup of the files & database from remote server and then copied the files & installed the db  on my localhost but it is giving this error:

> Site off-line We are currently under
>   maintenance. We should be back
>   shortly. Sorry for this inconvenience.

I've changed the settings.php to my localhost db and also retained the localhost version of .htaccess

I've also done such transfers for drupal sites but this time I can figure out what is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What Berkes is suggesting is the right answer.  I'm adding this as another answer so I can post SQL if that is not working.

Basically, user ID 1 should be able to see the site as if it were out of maintenance mode, even if it is in maintenance mode.

If you login at the /user screen, and you still see maintenance mode, then you are probably not logging in as user 1.

So if you want to force your site out of maintenance mode from MySQL queries, you can try to force the variable with this:

```
UPDATE variable SET value='s:1:"0";' WHERE name = 'site_offline';
DELETE FROM cache WHERE CID = 'variables';
```

Comment: Thanks but I did one more additional step after the steps you've mentioned: emptied all cache tables manually in phpmyadmin, otherwise it wasn't working anyway I tried.

Answer (score 1):

That message shows up when you have switched site in maintainance mode.

1. Visit "login", usually example.com/user
2. Log in with user-1, superuser.
3. Browse to `Administer » Site configuration » Site maintenance`
4. Switch site back to online.

If, for some reason the site is listed as `online` there, see the watchdog error messages (Administer » Log » Database logging). And post any information or errors you find there.

If the setting is set to offline, and cannot be changed to online, refer to the database logging too, if nothing found there, look in settings.php and see if the online/offline setting is hardcoded in that file.

Comment: I forgot to tell, if I go to site/admin it shows the same message. Where can I see the db logging?

Comment: I remember now that I took the backup of db after putting the site offline using mysqldump.

Comment: You must log in as user-1 first. *Then* visit site/admin